# Export/print QGis: dismatching OSM data on an OSM-layer

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, coordinate-system, export

On QGIS (2.10, winXP).

is there any known problem by exporting or printing .osm-data (from JOSM) onto an Openstreetmap-Mapnik-layer?
The imported waypoints always shift from the left less and less to the right-/east side of the map. On the left side, they seem to be good, but on 2.5 Km to the left, they are wrong for about -20 to -100 m - the .osm-data-layer seems to become smaller.

I adjusted the coordinate system for QGis
von QGIS +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

the layer of the waypoints is "WGS 84, EPSG 4326"
+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

the OSM-layer is "WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator, EPSG 3857"
+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs

might this mistake caused by mismatching coordinate systems?
But it seems for me, that I can't change the systems?